# 'Send Photo via WhatsApp' action not working in iPhone shortcuts

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app, shortcuts-app, heic

I am trying to create a shortcut on iPhone which will convert my photos from `*.heic` to `*.jpeg` and then send it on WhatsApp as a photo. Below is the screenshot of my shortcut.

[image]

But the shortcut does not work. It shows selection of Photos from my phone, but does not show up WhatsApp with photos to send to recipients. What am I missing here?